# Ingest JDBC/ODBC data to Snowflake

Tags: netsuite, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does Snowflake support JDBC data sources, and if so how? I'm using Netsuite Analytics as a datasource and would like to load that to a Snowflake warehouse. The examples I'm finding for SnowFlake are file readers, I realise I can convert my netsuite data to a file and then ingest that but I'd rather remove that additonal step.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake has both ODBC and JDBC drivers that you can use.  However, if you are loading a lot of data from Netsuite Analytics, most of the Snowflake drivers will actually generate files, PUT them to S3, and execute a COPY INTO statement to get the data into Snowflake for you.  While it is more seamless, it is still executing that "additional step".  The reason is...that's the most efficient way to get data into Snowflake, and it's not even close.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html

Comment: The ODBC and JDBC drivers for Snowflake are for reading data out of Snowflake from an external application. They do not offer functionality for loading data in to Snowflake from an external source, unless you were to develop a bespoke application to read the data from the external source and then write it to the database using INSERT statements, which would be very inefficient.

Comment: To say that Snowflake's ODBC and JDBC drivers are only for reading data out of Snowflake isn't an accurate statement, and there are other methods to load data into Snowflake leveraging those drivers other than INSERT statements.

Comment: If you're talking about using PUT, which s supported by the Snowflake drivers as a custom feature, then the question specifically asks how to load data *without using files*. The OP wants to know how to load data using ODBC/JDBC but without using files and as far as I know that's not possible without a third party tool.

Answer (score -1):

No, Snowflake doesn't offer tools for loading data from JDBC or ODBC data sources. This is because Snowflake is a database platform and the functionality you're describing is that of a data integration or ETL tool. There are plenty of third party tools available that can handle this such as Matillion or Talend. Snowflake has a list of recommended technology partners [on their website](https://www.snowflake.com/partners/technology-partners/).

If you don't have access to an ETL tool then, as you mentioned, you can create a process yourself to export data from Netsuite to files that are uploaded to cloud storage such AWS S3. You can then set up this storage area an "external stage" and [use Snowflake's COPY statement to load the data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide-data-load.html) into Snowflake.

Comment: You can also PUT into Snowflake's internal stage from most of Snowflake's drivers and then execute a COPY INTO from there.

Comment: Many of Snowflake's partners have Snowflake drivers of their own, as well, which allow you to load data into Snowflake directly from their application.  Many of those leverage Snowflake's ODBC and JDBC drivers natively.

Comment: Yep, PUT exists, but that involves creating files first - the question is can data be loaded from JDBC/ODBC data sources into Snowflake without creating files. There is no feature of Snowflake that makes this possible, you would need a third party tool. Also you keep referring to Snowflake ODBC or JDBC drivers but these are are for connecting to Snowflake, not an *external* data source as described in the question.